# localize UIAlertView & offline notifications in project with no storyboard

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, xcode7.2

I'm working on a project that doesn't have any `storyboards`. So I can't use "base internationalization"

I've created localizable.string then turned on localization for each required languages.

Then tried doing

```
- UIAlertView * messageBox = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:
                                                   NSLocalizedString(@"title", nil)
                                                   message: NSLocalizedString(@"msg", nil)
                                                   delegate: self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"ok", nil)
                                                   otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

And for notification i'm using nsdictionary and store notifications as:

```
 - [alertMessages setObject:NSLocalizedString(@"test_notification", nil)
   forKey:@"6"];
```

but it doesn't do any changes when changing language of the device. Is there any step i'm missing or if any better method is there? any working references would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: show me title, msg and ok in Localizable.strings file.

Comment: in localizable,strings (English)

"title" = "congratulations!";
"msg" = "You've completed all the levels";
"ok" = "got it";

in localizable.strings (French)

"title"="Félicitations !";
"msg"="Vous avez terminé tous les niveaux";
"ok"="COMPRIS"

Comment: Delete App, and Clean, than RUN AGAIN.

Comment: What's the exact name of the strings file? Is it localizable.strings or Localizable.strings. It should be the latter since the filenames are case sensitive in the device. Also to which language setting are you changing the device to?

Comment: it is later one - i did french ofcourse :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**

Do the following steps.

> 1. Clean Project
> 2. Delete App From Device/Simulator
> 3. If Simulator - Reset it.
> 4. Delete Derived Files (XCode > Window > Projects > Derived Data Delete)
> 5. Install App, and it will work.

I think its simply Cache Issue.

**SOLUTION 2:**

NSLocalizedString uses Localizable.strings file by default. Change your File.strings name and try again.

> NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Message", @"File");

Comment: great.. solution 2 worked for me!
i was using NSLocalizedString  but NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Message", @"File", comment); did the trick.

Comment: My Pleasure :) Happy Coding.